# Disabling the Cinnamon Systray is not possible?

Tags: cinnamon, tint2

I want to replace the Cinnamon Panel with `tint2`. 
Unfortunately, I cant get the `tint2` systray running, as the Cinnamon process is already using it.

I removed all panels, but Cinnamon is still blocking the systray.

Any help regarding this? I couldn't find anything via Google.

```
tint2 : another systray is running pid=7539

lybs@aspire:~$ ps aux | grep 7539

lybs      7539  8.6  3.8 1902764 315524 ?      Sl   06:30   3:38 cinnamon --replace
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cinnamon panel (which contains the systray) is an integral part of Cinnamon and thus can't be disabled or halted. The only way to achieve a hidden effect is using auto-hide mode or setting the height of the taskbar to be zero pixels. However, this is only hiding the panel and not stopping it. Unfortunately, that means that there isn't a way to stop the Cinnamon panel.

You'd probably want to try a using a different desktop environment, or not using one at all.